# Как динамически обновлять текст в Label, при его изменении в цикле (Java)?

Tags: java, swing

Есть два класса: Second и Third. Оба отображают окно JFrame. На первом окне есть только Label, на втором только Button. 
Вопрос: как при нажатии кнопки Button во втором окне сделать чтобы по циклу менялась надпись на Label в первом окне. 
Пока получается что надпись обновляется только в конце цикла ...

Собственно главный метод Main:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Second app = new Second();
        app.setVisible(true);
        Third app2 = new Third();
        app2.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Класс Second:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Second extends JFrame{
    public static JLabel label;
    Second(){
        super("Окно которым управляют");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(450, 300);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label = new JLabel("0");
        panel.add(label);
        setContentPane(panel);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

И класс Third:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class Third extends JFrame{

    Third(){
        super("Окно которое управляет");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(450, 300);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       JButton button = new JButton("Запустить цикл");

        button.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                buttonMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);
        setContentPane(panel);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void buttonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        for (int i =0; i <5; i++) {
            Second.label.setText("Number " + i);
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо откорректировать метод buttonMouseClicked.
Так как отрисовка происходит в другом потоке, необходимо код обернуть в класс SwingWorker.
Как то так:

```
    public void buttonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        SwingWorker swingWorker = new SwingWorker() {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    process(Arrays.asList("Number " + i));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List chunks) {
                Second.label.setText(String.valueOf(chunks.get(0)));
            }
        };

        swingWorker.execute();
    }
```

Очень [полезная статья](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/synchronization.html)

Comment: Cпасибо ezhov_da! Моя IDE (IntelijIdea) немного ругалась на приведенный Вами код, но смысл я уловил и благодаря ссылке на статью решил свой вопрос, теперь все работает как надо!

Comment: только не `process(Arrays.asList("Number " + i));`, а `publish("Number " + i);`

Comment: Точно, спасибо, давно это было )

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря ответу от ezhov_da нашел работающее решение. Вот мой рабочий код, может кому пригодится:
Класс Third

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Third extends JFrame{
    public int i;
    Third(){
        super("Окно которое управляет");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(450, 300);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       JButton button = new JButton("Запустить цикл");



        button.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                buttonMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);
        setContentPane(panel);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void buttonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        guiWithoutBrakes withoutBrakes =new guiWithoutBrakes();
        withoutBrakes.execute();
    }

    public class guiWithoutBrakes extends SwingWorker<Integer, Object> {
        private static final long SLEEP_TIME=1000;
        public int doSomeWork()
        {
            for (i =0; i <5; i++) {
                Second.label.setText("Number " + i);
                Second.label.revalidate();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground() {
            return new Integer(doSomeWork());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Label(имею в виду имя объекта label).setText("");

Comment: Это я сделал в цикле при нажатии кнопки: Second.label.setText("Number " + i);

Comment: В ходе работы цикла значение Label не обновляется. Обновляется только когда цикл отработал...

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет т.к сам недавно искал такой метод

`repaint();` перерисовывает фрэйм, тем самым обновляет  надписи, добавь его в цикл и вуоля, если ты про это))

Comment: Митяй, не помогло... Пробовал просто добавить repaint(); и пробовал добавить repaint() к panel: Second.panel.repaint(), предварительно объявив panel публичной и статической переменной в класе Second...