# Как мне отрисовать что-то в потоке на панели, которая находится не в потоке

Tags: java, многопоточность, gui, swing

Как мне что-либо отрисовать на панели класса `JPanel panel` в другом потоке,

**пример кода ниже:**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{
public static void main (String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    frame.add(this);
    frame.add(panel);

    Thread thread = new Thread(()->{
        //тут должен быть код для отрисовки графики на панели panel
    });
}

public void paint (Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawOval(0,0,500,500);
}
```

}

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как динамически обновлять текст в Label, при его изменении в цикле (Java)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801167/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2-label-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-java)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отрисовать в потоке надо вызывать метод `repaint()` того фрейма где происходит отрисовка.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(()->{
   //тут должен быть код для отрисовки графики на панели panel
   frame.repaint();
});
```

Почему так можно делать:

### [Рисование в AWT и Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html#)

> `JComponent.repaint()` регистрирует асинхронный запрос на перерисовку в `RepaintManager` компонента, который использует `invokeLater()` для постановки `Runnable` в очередь для последующей обработки запроса в потоке диспетчеризации событий.

Comment: Нельзя так делать. Во всяком случае в Swing/AWT точно, но скорее всего и во всех остальных UI библиотеках (не только Java), вся работа с УИ должна осуществляться из UI-thread

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Обновил ответ.

Comment: @breat Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.

Answer (score -1):

Из других потоков рисовать можно только используя

[SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))

или

[SwintUtilities.invokeAndWait](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait(java.lang.Runnable))

или

[SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Например,

```
Thread thread = new Thread(()->{
   // тут подготовка/загрузка данных, сложные вычисления
   ...
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
     //тут можно дергать методы компонентов Swing panel
     ...
   
   });
   
});
```

Comment: Ну и зачем тут invokeLater в потоке?  Этот метод возвращает управление немедленно, ток, что поток сразу завершается.

Comment: @RomanC Если человеку нужен цикл, он его сам добавит. В твоём варианте поток тоже сразу завершается, но ты почему-то проблемы в этом не увидел ;)

Comment: В моем варианте я показал как отрисовать, а дальше пусть сам разберётся. А в твоём варианте нет отрисовки.